# Rasa: cafe chatbot wrong response

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, rasa

I'm building a simple Rasa NLU chatbot for the cafe using Google Colab and I have encounter a problem on the chat bot response in which some of responses from the chatbot are given wrongly/different when I put on some inputs. For example,

```
User:hi

Bot:Hey There! Welcome to Polar Bear Cafe. What would like to order?

User:What type of pretzels do you offer?

Bot:We offer two types of pretzels which is hard and soft.

User:What type of hard pretzel do you serve?

Bot:We usually sell rice, noodles, western food and breakfast set which is only available in 
    the morning from 7 am to 11 am.

User:/stop
```

The chatbot answer is supposed to be "The types of hard pretzel we serve are basic twist, pretzel stick, nugget, big soft pretzel, pretzel crisps and German pretzels. " when I put the "What type of hard pretzel do you serve?" as an input on the chatbot.

However, there are no errors on the nlu.md file, domain.yml file and stories.yml file What changes do I need to do for the rasa chatbot to fix the error?

[Rasa Chatbot responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpzqw.png)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add entities into yours nlu.yml to every single intent from which your bot can differentiate between different intents and than run command "rasa shell --debug" to see the  which entities are associated to which intents.
You must add entities into yours nlu.yml file and second if still not getting what you want you can run command mentioned above and see what is the problem with it.
and last from my personal experience use pycharam as IDE as its show you extra warning in CLI that can be helpful to debug .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because you have not created proper story for this situation. You need to create a story in "stories.yml" file accordingly bot will utter the answers for specific intent.

Comment: The Question you are trying to answer is not providing a lot of information. Since the rasa chat bot is a ML Model approach your answer is pointing in the right direction. But since some code (the  mentioned md-file and yml-file and maybe more) is missing, your answer is at the state of the question better used as a comment for the author. After the question author provides more information and you are able to describe better how to approach her/his problem your answer will be more usefull for everybody.